# Google Bookmarks Lists

Tags: google-bookmarks

I would like to find out if Google Bookmarks has any public lists worth following. Unfortunately, it doesn't have anything for rating lists or recommmended lists ect. Does anyone have any ideas for finding lists with good quality content?

Comment: It is such an under utilized feature I doubt if any curation exists for this tool. You will have much better luck using http://delicious.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea for finding items (taken from [the Google Operating System blog](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/10/find-great-pages-using-google-bookmarks.html))

In [Google Bookmarks](http://www.google.com/bookmarks), search for a site you know has content that you are interested in.  For example, I searched for "`http://www.perl.com`".  The [search results](http://www.google.com/bookmarks/l#!view=threadsmgmt&fo=Pub&g=None&q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.perl.com) are 3 lists (one of them is dead) that contain perl.com.  Both of the remaining lists look pretty interesting to me.

It's not a direct way to search public lists, but it produces some interesting results that have come in handy for me.